# Clicking on class

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have an Javascript `$("#inventory").on('click', ".item-card", function() {`, at the moment it works if you gonna click on that `item-card` then it does that stuff.. Can I somehow change it to, if you gonna click class button? But the `item-card` has to remain because it uses some `$(this)` functions.. That's why I haven't figured it out yet myself :/.

### HTML

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<li class='col 2 zoomIn animated'>
    <div class='card item-card waves-effect waves-light'>
        <div class='iteam'>" + item.name + "</div>
        <div class='condition'>" + item.condition + "</div>
        <div class='center-align'></div>
        <div class='secondarea'>
            <div class='buyer-price center-align'>$" + item.price + "
                <div class='bitskinscomp'>" + message + "</div>
                <div class='float'>Float value: " + item.floatvalue + "</div>
            </div>
            <a class='btn waves-effect waves-light'>Cart</a>
        </div>
</li>
```

### jQuery

```
$("#inventory").on('click', ".item-card", function () {
```

Comment: Do you want one button for each .item-card? An HTML snippet would be helpful to go along with your question.

Comment: Sounds like you just want to `find()` the `.item-card` inside `this`?

Comment: That is one of the soupiest code bits I have ever seen. It would help you and others if it was both 1) formatted better and 2) the compiled inline styles were removed (unless you're actually literally writing inline styles, and then we have a whole set of other problems).

Comment: And please replace whatever the backend code that you have in there in various places with accurate placeholders. Escaped quotes and such are just a mess to look at especially if we can't tell exactly what will be in the field anyway.

Comment: I changed HTML code.

Comment: I could explain better, what I'm trying to do if someone didn't understood.

Comment: I don't understand it, a rewrite if the question would be a start

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is:

```
$("#inventory").on("click", ".item-card a.btn", function() {
    var card = $(this).closest(".item-card");
    ...
});
```

In the rest of the code you use `card` wherever you used `$(this)` in the original code.